# Last k digits of Powers of 2

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

> For any integer \$r\$, there exists a
> power of 2 each of whose last \$r\$ digits
> are either 1 or 2.

Given \$r\$, find the smallest \$x\$ such that \$2^x\bmod{10^r}\$ consists of only 1 or 2.

For \$r=2\$, \$x=9\$, since \$2^9=5\color{blue}{\textrm{12}}\$
For \$r=3\$, \$x=89\$, since \$2^{89}=618970019642690137449562\color{blue}{\textrm{112}}\$
Note: for \$r=4\$, \$x\$ is \$=89\$ (again)

Input : \$r \leq 100\$

Output : \$x\$

Eg.

> Input : 2
> Ouput : 9
>
> Input : 3
> Ouput : 89

The program should run in a reasonable amount of time.

EDIT: The oeis sequence for this challenge is [A147884](http://oeis.org/A147884).

Comment: The OEIS for this task is [A147884](http://oeis.org/A147884)

Comment: @Debanjan, yes true. @S.Mark, powers of 2, not 3.

Comment: I have a paper, which describes an efficient algorithm. i'll post it if someone can't get move forward with it.

Comment: @st0le:Complexity?

Comment: @whacko_Cracko, err, i'm pretty sure it's linear (not sure though)...there's a pattern to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 166 chars

```
k,f,g=1,4,16
i=j=2
n=input()
m=10**n
a=lambda c:c('')-1-i or c('1')+c('2')-c('')+1
while i<=n:
 while a(str(j)[-i:].count):j,k=j*g%m,k+f
 i,g,f=i+1,g**5%m,f*5
print k
```

Comment: Great job, Mark :) I guess you found it :)

Comment: You can save a few bytes using semicolons: [161 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYnLDoIwEEX38xXdGPrCWBQXxfkS46KiwPAoBEuMX18bXd1zzl0@oZt9EeOgG92i0SdtzkDYYwEeyS9b4AImNAcpPTgc3XR/OFbbmmeZyCk388oSm0yoNEVqv0cZeHc0Phld0Ftgf3H8FVbei2tO9rav580HYXuJ7W6qBoUNMFJoqhZbKcvUGoklLCv5wIYYj18 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
(x=0;While[Max@Abs[2IntegerDigits[2^++x,10,#]-3]>1];x)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@1@jwtbAOjwjMyc12jexwsExqTjayDOvJDU9tcglMz2zBMiN09au0DE00FGO1TWOtTOMta7QVPvvWFSUWBntpqNgaBD7/79uQVFmXgkA)

[`IntegerDigits[a,10,r]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) generates a list of the `r` last decimal digits of `a`. Subtract 3/2 and check that they are all either -1/2 or +1/2.

Timing check: 20 seconds on TIO for `r = 1 .. 10`.

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>102</s> <s>95</s> <s>91</s> 89 bytes

```
k/.FindInstance[Mod[n=0;Nest[#+10^n(2-Mod[#/2^n++,2])&,0,#]-2^k,5^#]==0,k,Integers][[1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCgIhEADQX1kQlsKxVaFTeOgS7KF@YBhBdt0S2SnUS19v9I5vD@0V99DSEvo2uJ6n0y3xOnNtgZeI9/eK7PTlEWtDIY32fLDqv2KynqUES8cRNAhS1mc4e0HOacgwc4vPWCohGqKxX0sJX9xgMJZ6V5@SuP0A)

This solution is much longer but much faster. By taking the path suggested in [OEIS A147884](http://oeis.org/A147884) to go via [OEIS A053312](http://oeis.org/A053312), as well as using [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) magic, TIO manages to compute `r = 1 .. 12` in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 118 chars

```
k,f,g,m=1,4,16
i=j=2
m=10**(n=gets.to_i)
((k+=f;j=j*g%m)until j.to_s=~%r{[12]{#{i}}$};i+=1;f*=5;g=g**5%m)until n<i
p k
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 115 characters

```
import List
main=readLn>>=print. \r->head$findIndices(all(`elem`"12").take r.(++cycle"0").reverse.show)$iterate(*2)1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda i,c=2:f(i,c+1)if{*str(2**c)[-i:]}-{*'12'}else c**(i>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYuxDsIgFAB3v4K4FJ5tIzUOktQfMQ6IoC8pjwZwaAjfXhkut9ytW/4Guuzo1xAzS1s6NMZkc7TmFxMGWtBj5vIMcBW7mxftX2/NsDfzpBxvPkmBrkDKkU8ARjwGVM86FOjk1FW7JMsMAMe7bH@IjBgSi5o@lsv@JtQakTI/lqpYqcexJV5nTr3jJITY/w)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞.Δo©‹®I.£2X:`P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//@KIni7OlG/CqeKAucKuSS7CozJYOmBQ//8z) or [verify the first 8 test cases](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX/OEVOPyIg4oaSICI/Tlb/4oieLs6Ub8KpWXPigLnCrlkuwqMyWDpgUP99LP8) (any more times out).

**Explanation:**

Uses the fact that \$2^x > r\$ for all possible results, to ensure we have enough digits to get the last \$r\$ digits of \$2^x\$.

```python
∞.Δ            # Find the first positive integer x which is truthy (==1) for:
   o           #  Take 2 to the power the integer: 2^x
    ©          #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
     ‹         #  Check that it's larger than the (implicit) input: r < 2^x
               #  (1 if truhy; 0 if falsey)
    ®          #  Push variable `®` again: 2^x
     I.£       #  Only leave the last input amount of digits
        2X:    #  Replace all 2s with 1s
           `   #  Push all digits separated to the stack
    P          #  Take the product of all digits on the stack (including the earlier check)
               #  (NOTE: Only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### CSharp - 111 chars

```
int a(int r){int x=1;a:x++;foreach(var c in Math.Pow(2,x)%Math.Pow(10,r)+"")if(c!='1'&&c!='2')goto a;return x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint -p`, 33 bytes

```perl
1while($a=2**++$\)!~/[12]{$_}$/}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1VDJdHWSEtLW1slRlOxTj/a0Ci2WiW@VkW/tvr/f/N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNgHRSZnpmXsl/3QIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/) <s>133</s> 122 (51) bytes

Inspired by YOU's answer:

```julia
n->(k=1;f=4;g=big(16);i=j=2;m=10^n;while i<=n;while digits!(fill(0,i),j)⊈1:2;j,k=j*g%m,k+f;end;i,g,f=i+1,g^5%m,f*5end;k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1BDoIwEEDRq@jCpAOVdFBcMI5HIdFA67SlMYrRIxiP6UUqLtz9vM339yhHfGbLOa0PKjCS5S05PolTuAMS9lzTyGi6RI@zxGEhe/5nL06m21JZiVEZLaA9fN4vbGvyOrAv3GrUobQ0pJ5EO21ZStSua2a3RfPjAPlylTTFVClbqXlcKWw3BgDyFw)

The following is much shorter, but it crashes for r > 8, like some of the other answers:

```julia
f(r,x=big(1))=digits!(fill(0,r),x)⊈1:2&&f(r,2x)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jSKfCNikzXcNQU9M2JTM9s6RYUSMtMydHw0CnSFOnQvNRV4ehlZGaGkilUYWmtuH/gqLMvJKcPD2NND0NQysLTc3/AA)